# I can't see query variables on logging

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm encountering issues with debugging SQL queries. I've attempted to configure the settings below to enable query debugging, but it hasn't been successful.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Here is my Hibernate output. As you can see there are no provided values corresponding to "token" and "is_active".

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        c1_0.id,
        c1_0.bussiness_name,
        c1_0.is_active,
        c1_0.token 
    from
        credential c1_0 
    where
        c1_0.token=? 
        and c1_0.is_active
```

**Furthermore, these configurations flawlessly on Java 11 and MySQL. However, I'm puzzled as to what might be causing issues with PostgreSQL 15 and Java 21.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem while replacing `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE` with `logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE`

And those were unnecessary

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```